# CPS in OCaml: type doesn't check

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm working on a very simple OCaml exercise on CPS. Line 8-10 is to convert two recursive calls into one tail recursion. However, the compiler complains the type of Line 8:

> File "tmp.ml", line 8, characters 9-14:
>
> Error: This expression has type int -> int -> (int -> int) -> int
>          but an expression was expected of type int

I understand that the compiler expects an `int` at line 8 because line 6 returns an `int`. But can someone illustrate why the type of Line 8-10 is not an int?

```
  4 let rec f i n k (i:int) (n:int) (k:int->int) :int =
  5     if i + n < 0 then
  6         k 1
  7     else
  8         (f i (n-1) (fun v ->
  9             f (i-1) n (fun vv->
 10                 k (v + vv))))
 11 in f 1 1 (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: Have you tried to leave out the type annotation? Very easy to infer the types from the operators used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f i n-1` is parsed as `(f i n)-1` rather than the `f i (n-1)` you presumably expect.

Additionally,

```
let rec f i n k (i:int) (n:int) (k:int->int) :int
```

means that your function takes **6** arguments: `i`, `n`, `k`, `i`, `n` and `k`. You probably meant to write:

```
let rec f (i:int) (n:int) (k:int->int) :int
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. That eliminates the `'a`, but type still doesn't check. I've updated the text.

Comment: @qweruiop I've updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: I confirm it typechecks with `let rec f (i:int) (n:int) (k:int->int) :int`.